# Downloading GUI for a wpf desktop application

Tags: wpf, architecture, mef

I am developer of an wpf application which will be deployed among various locations in my city. My applications GUI will change with respect to the season. I am planning to write the application using MEF/MVVM so that i can isolate the GUI part to  a seperate dll and  download the new version when available. Recently, I came to know about XAP. Is it possible to put the GUI files in XAP and download it when needed? Is it possible to  have a silverlight plugin inside a WPF application?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to put the GUI files in XAP and download it when
>   needed?

Surely, you can. I'd recommend reading about [Prism](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921153%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx) for information about how to build modular apps in WPF. Basic idea is to dynamically load needed assemblies, reference their resources and put their content  onto the page. MEF is used to import declarations of components/user controls.

> Is it possible to have a silverlight plugin inside a WPF application?

Sure, you can do that. One of the ways is to integrate webBrowser control onto your page and set its location to XAP file, though it looks like an overkill.